# How to create a weekly email summarizing new content from multiple lists?

Tags: 2007, list, workflow, email

I've been tasked to create a week in review email that summarizes the latest news, events, job postings, and new documents on our intranet. However, they are currently all on separate lists. Is there a way of combining the lists in one email and sending it out every Friday? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

While this won't technically answer your question, I'd propose an alternate solution. With all the data being list driven, you could create a newsletter page that rolls this data up, via content query web parts or cross list dataview web parts. These can be filtered to show items created in the last 5 days so you always have a rolling display of fresh content.

Then on Fridays, you remind people of this dashboard page and drive users there, then you can scale back the notifications once people are familiar with the site and can do self service updates as needed.

The content lives in SharePoint, drive the people there to consume it. This will also help adoption and interest in using the platform.

Comment: I agree. I will be implementing this when we roll out SP2013 next year. However, I need an interm solution to satisfy my managers. I appreciate your feedback. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a timer job which will look into all lists for the new content and send a mail to the users.